# Does it matter how you connect to sql within your php

Tags: php, sql

I have a website with multiple forms and currently the PHP for each form has the code which connects to the SQL within it. Whereas I have seen some people who have a file e.g mysql_connect which they refer to every time instead of having the connection code in every PHP file.

Are there any advantages and disadvantages to each because I can't see any which would make it worth changing my code however I would just like to make sure I am doing things the best way :) Also are either considered to be best practice or is it subjective? 
Thanks :)

Comment: Code re-use is generally valuable. If you will connect to the same data source each time, write that code just once and re-use it where needed.  Performance-wise, if you are writing connection code at point of need, you run the risk of opening more connections than needed, which is a waste of resources and sometimes actively harmful if you use up your allotted connections.

Comment: Typically people store configuration details in one file. Depending on your organizational preferences you can make a database class that uses those credentials, a function in a common file that returns the connection, or do as you do and just write out the code over and over. Looking into MVC will show you what is typical and preferred

Answer (score 2):

One the the single biggest advantages to having the connect info in a single file is a single point to edit.  When you are first starting, this doesn't seem like a big deal... but managing and editing your code as the site becomes more complex can be very troublesome, if you are having to go into each file and change the connection information.

As far as best practice goes, for coding in general... if you are having to repeat logic/information in multiple places... there is a good chance it should be put into a function/method and than referenced.  This line of reasoning, I feel, applies to the connect info as well. in addition to maintenance gains, it also improves readability of your code.

There are many other references out there, but [here](http://www.phptherightway.com/) is an online one that has some suggestions and "best practices" for php.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 main benefits on having the connection logic on a separate file you require.

1. [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). By not repeating it's easier to change and mantain (password, connection string, database name, setting properties to the connection).
2. It's a good idea to keep everything that is not used strictly to generate the view away from your document root; in a separate folder. This makes sure that, even if your server ever gets misconfigured (and therefore stops executing PHP files to just serve them as static files) noone can download you database connection configuration, helping in keeping it safe. Also this is a good thing to keep separation of concerns, one of the main drivers behind patterns such as MVC, but that's probably outside the scope of your question.

Comment: plus 1 for `Don't repeat yourself`

Comment: Agreed.  acronyms always help to root the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your password is compromised. You change your password.

Would you rather change a single configuration file, or to go through every single file and update your password... actually, do you even want your password saved in *every file*?